# PHP Adding to JSON Array - "Illegal offset type"

Tags: php, json

I have some arrays:

`$officers` & `$dates`

Each `$officers` has two arrays (`$i` being officers number):

`${'raw_tot_data_'.$i}` & `${'raw_pd_data_'.$i}`

these respectively being (if `$i=0`):

`$raw_tot_data_0` & `$raw_pd_data_0`

Now I currently have a `JSON` array (`$ourData`) which looks similar to:

```
//$ourData
[
    //$officer_0
    {
        "code": "cg",
        "tots": [],
        "pds": []
    },
    //$officer_1
    {
        "code": "crg",
        "tots": [],
        "pds": []
    },
    //$officer_2
    {
        "code": "jan",
        "tots": [],
        "pds": []
    },
    ...
```

I would like to populate each officers `tots` and `pds`. To do that I attempted the following (this is pre `json_encode($ourData)`):

```
$i=0;
foreach($officers as $officer){
    $n=0;
    foreach($dates as $date){

        $tmp = ${'officer_'.$i};

        $ourData[$tmp]['tots'][$n] = (    //error here
            $date.' : '.${'raw_tot_data_'.$i}[$n]
        );
        $ourData[$tmp]['pds'][$n] = (    //error here
            $date.' : '. ${'raw_pd_data_'.$i}[$n]
        );

        $n++;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

This returns errors stating

> Illegal offset type

after some research I found this:

> Illegal offset type errors occur when you attempt to access an array index using an object or an array as the index key.

How could I correct this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value here...

```
$tmp = ${'officer_'.$i};
```

Is setting `$tmp` to the value of a variable, when (I think) you want it to be just the string itself...

```
$tmp = 'officer_'.$i;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response you are correct, I also had to change a bit of my code before this issue but this helped me